# C# - String Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I am attempting to code a mini-game. I am new to C#. The first thing I want to do is have a string array that holds names of enemies.

```
string[] Opponents = new string[]
{
"enemy1", "enemy2", "enemy3", "enemy4", "enemy5", "enemy6", "enemy7", "enemy8", "enemy9", "enemy10", "enemy11", "enemy12", "enemy13", "enemy14", "enemy15", "enemy16", "enemy17", "enemy18", "enemy19", "enemy20", "enemy21", "enemy22", "enemy23", "enemy24", "enemy25", "enemy26", "enemy27", "enemy28", "enemy29", "enemy30", "enemy31", "enemy32", "enemy33", "enemy34", "enemy35", "enemy36", "enemy37"
};
```

I want to take this string and use the values to make waves of 5 enemies. Each time a wave is displayed, I would like to have 3 enemies removed and the next wave include 2 new enemies, placing them at the beginning of the wave. If the wave only has 3 enemies left, the next wave will have a new set of 5 (or whatever is left in he array) I would like it to look like this:

Wave 1: enemy1, enemy2, enemy3, enemy4, enemy5

Wave 2: enemy6, enemy7, enemy4, enemy5

Wave 3: enemy8, enemy9, enemy5

Wave 4: enemy10, enemy11, enemy12, enemy13, enemy14

etc...

This should be possible with any length of the array as the number of enemies later on will change.

I know I need to use a loop to do so, but I am having trouble...

This is what I have started with:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            Game game = new Game();
            game.Waves();

            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        class Game
        {

            public void Waves()
            {

                    string[] Opponents = new string[]
                    {
                     "enemy1", "enemy2", "enemy3", "enemy4", "enemy5", "enemy6", "enemy7", "enemy8", "enemy9", "enemy10", "enemy11", "enemy12", "enemy13", "enemy14", "enemy15", "enemy16", "enemy17", "enemy18", "enemy19", "enemy20", "enemy21", "enemy22", "enemy23", "enemy24", "enemy25", "enemy26", "enemy27", "enemy28", "enemy29", "enemy30", "enemy31", "enemy32", "enemy33", "enemy34", "enemy35", "enemy36", "enemy37"
                    };

                string[] activeWave = new string[5];
                Array.Copy(Opponents, 0, activeWave, 0, 5);

                Console.WriteLine("Current wave of opponents: " + activeWave[0] + ", " + activeWave[1] + ", " + activeWave[2] + ", " + activeWave[3] + ", " + activeWave[4]);

            }


        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Am I even on the right path?

Comment: I would advise looking into queues, from what it sounds like you want to do, I think they would be very helpful!

Comment: sorry to say but I am still not clear what exactly you want from the **Opponents** array

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not". ... and please: give your question a more meaningful title!

Answer (score 2):

I've drafted up a solution using queues.  I'm not really that good at C#, so I'm sure there's a couple of syntax errors and typos, but I hope this gets you on the right track.

```
class Program{
    string [] Opponents             = ...;
    int       currentPlace          = 0;
    int       curWaveNum            = 0;
    int       newWaveSize           = 5;
    int       newEnemiesPerWave     = 2;
    int       enemiesRemovedPerWave = 3;

    // Creates a queue, or a "FIFO" (First In, First Out) data structure.
    Queue myQ = newQueue();

    void addWave(){
        // Remove enemies until you've gotten to enemiesRemovedPerWave, or until the
        // wave is empty
        for(int i = 0 ; i < enemiesRemovedPerWave ; i++){
            if(myQ.count == 0){
                break;
            }
            myQ.Dequeue();
        }

        // Set toAdd to be newWaveSize if the queue is empty, or newEnemiesPerWave if
        // it's not empty
        int toAdd = (myQ.count == 0 ? newWaveSize : newEnemiesPerWave);

        // Add the enemies to the queue, from the Opponents array
        for(int i = 0 ; i < toAdd ; i++){
            // If there's only one enemy left in the Opponents array, only attempt 
            // to add one enemy to myQ
            if(currentPlace + i >= Opponents.count){
                break;
            }
            else{
                // Actually add to the queue
                myQ.enqueue(Opponents[currentPlace + i]);
            }
        }
        // Update currentPlace.  Note that you could have the above for loop be:
        // for( ; currentPlace < currentPlace + toAdd ; currentPlace++)
        // but I think how I wrote it is easier to understand
        currentPlace += toAdd;
    }
    void printWave(){
        Console.write("Wave %d: ", waveNum);
        // Print everything but the last one
        for(int i = 0 ; i < myQ.count - 1 ; i++){
            Console.write(myQ[i] + ", ");
        }
        Console.write(myQ[myQ.count - 1] + "\n");
    }
    public void play(){
        while(currentPlace < Opponents.count){
            addWave();
            printWave();
            curWaveNum++;
        }
    }
}
```

The key to this is a data structure called a Queue.  Think of it as an actual queue (line) at a store--the first people to get in line are served first.  This is in contrast to a "LIFO" data structure, known as a Stack.  A Stack behaves like, well, a stack of pancakes.  When you make pancakes, you typically put the newest cooked ones on top, meaning the first pancake to bee taken will be the last one that was made, hence "LIFO," or "Last In, First Out."

You can read more about the functions defined for queues [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)!

Edit: Added `printWave` and `play`

Comment: This seems good, I am trying to understand how it works though.

Where would I put my

Console.WriteLine("Wave1: " + myQ);

Console.WriteLine("Wave2: " + myQ);

etc..

To get:

Wave 1: enemy1, enemy2, enemy3, enemy4, enemy5
-
Wave 2: enemy6, enemy7, enemy4, enemy5
-
Wave 3: enemy8, enemy9, enemy5
-
Wave 4: enemy10, enemy11, enemy12, enemy13, enemy14
-
etc...

Comment: @user3029953 You have your `Opponents` array, which does not change.  There is also `myQ`, which is of type `Queue`.  You can think of a `Queue` as a regular array, but the fundamental definition of a `Queue` is that `Enqueue` puts something at the end (after the previous thing `Enqueue`d), and `Dequeue` removes something from the front (i.e. the thing that `Enqueue`'d the longest time ago).  When `addWave` is called, it `Dequeue`s `enemiesRemovedPerWave`, then `Enqueue`s `newEnemiesPerWave` (or `newWaveSize`, if the wave is empty).  In this way, you know which ones were added most recently.

Comment: Yes, I believe I have understood the logic. I am simply having difficulty understanding where I would write the waves to the console. How do i get that Wave 1: ... Wave 2: ...  written to console for each time it queues. Maybe I have just been staring at the same code for too long but it's not clicking for me! I apologize for the ignorance.

Comment: @user3029953 You would want to iterate for as many waves as you want, and print out what is in the queue at each iteration.  I have written in (I think all of the?) safeguards you'll need, so even if you say 20 waves, the last 16 or so will just be empty.  You could also do something like `while(currentPlace < Opponents.count)`.

Comment: @user3029953 I've updated my post with some additional code that should at least give you the right direction to go in.